# PyQt/PySide Get Decimal Place of selected value in QSpinBOX

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

How to query Decimal Place of selected value in QSpinBox(PyQt) ?

Let say QSpinBox contain value 631.1205 and user select 3 then answer should be tens.(i.e 6=Hundreds, 3=Tens, 1=Ones, 1=Tenths, 2=Hundredths, 0=Thousandths, 5=Ten-Thousandths).

Comment: How is the user selecting "3"? As in the select the text 3 in the spin box? or Is there a drop down list? or what? What if the user selects more than one number?

Comment: It's normal QSpinBox (no any drop down list), user will select by mouse. if user select more thn one digit, result will be higher value(i.e 631 = Hundreds, 31=Tens, 205=Hundredths).

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have two lists that contain the text you want to return (expand beyond thousand*s if appropriate for your use case):
    big = ['Ones', 'Tens', Hundreds', 'Thousands']
    small = ['Tenths', 'Hundredths', 'Thousandths']

First you need to get a reference to the `QLineEdit` in the `QSpinBox` with:

```
line_edit = spinBox.findChild(QLineEdit)
```

Then find the index of where the selection starts:

```
selectionStart = line_edit.selectionStart()
```

Next find the index of the decimal point:

```
try:
    decimalPoint = str(line_edit.text()).index('.')
except ValueError:
    # no decimal point found so assume the number is an integer
    decimalPoint = len(str(line_edit.text()))
```

Then work out what you need to return:

```
# If something is selected
if selectionStart > -1:
    # if we have selected text starting on the left of the decimal
    if selectionStart < decimalPoint:
        return big[decimalPoint-selectionStart-1]
   # else we selected text starting on the right of the decimal
   else:
        return small[selectionStart-decimalPoint-1]
```

I'd recommend putting this in a function and calling it when appropriate as I have no context of what you are trying to do!